# Share Oracle Forms application on a local network

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, windows-server-2008-r2, oracleforms

In my local network i have a server (Windows Server R2) and two computers with Windows 7, in my server i have Oracle database 10g and Oracle Forms and Reports 6i installed along with my forms application, i want to share my application on the network, and the best way i could think of is:

On the server:

- Share the ORANT folder (`C:\orant\`).
- Share the application folder (`C:\app`).

On the client computer:

- Map a network drive for each folder, for example '`Y:`' for '`orant`' and '`Z:\`' for '`app`'.
- make a shortcut on the desktop of "`Y:\BIN\ifrun60.exe`"
- In the shortcut properties:

  -The target is : `Y:\BIN\ifrun60.EXE inicial.fmx`

  -Start in is: `Z:\`

I was wondering if that would work? Or do i have to do something else? is there a problem i should expect when doing this?

**PS:** *it's for a client, and i can't test anything unless i'm sure of it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to share my application on the network, i followed the next steps:

- Shared the application folder from the server.
- Installed oracle forms and reports 6i on each client machine.
- Created a shortcut to the ifrun60.exe with the starting form name (\server\app_dir\start.fmx) as the parameter and the application folder(\server\app_dir) as the start in.

[image]

- Added this to the tnsnames.ora file in each orant directory of each machine :

  `ORCL =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server_IP )(PORT = 1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
      )
    )`

and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The oracle runform client `ifrun60.EXE` needs a registry branch (it is necessary to copy the registry branch from the server) and also it is necessary to add paths to the PATH variable.

Comment: Could you please give me more details?

Comment: Should i export the whole "ORACLE" branch from the registry of the server and import it in my client registry? and what paths should i add?